# In how many ways can 3 employees visit 40 locations

Tags: combinatorics, permutation-cycles

Three employees need to visit 40 different cities under the following conditions: each location should be visited by exactly one employee, and no location should be visited multiple times. The travel agency should plan the tours for three employees. How many "tour" options are there in total?

Is the solution number of permutations with 3 cycles?

Comment: Could you edit to make a precise definition of what is distinguishable and what is not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to partition the given set of $40$ distinguishable locations into $3$ nonempty blocks, without naming the blocks. The number of ways this can be done is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $S(40,3)$ (there are various notations in use). The resulting number is
$$S(40,3)=2\,026\,277\,026\,753\,674\,246\ .$$

Comment: Thank you, now I see that I wasn't clear. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

For each location you have 3 chooises (employees)and you have 40 locations so $3^{40}$?

Comment: Are the three employees distinguishable ? do we double count assignment $A,B,C$ and $A,C,B$ for instance ?

Comment: No, they are not distinguishable.

Comment: Employees are not distinguishable? How come?

Comment: Employees are the same, like 3 stars.